# beamer and smart diagram - reverse overlay order for descriptive diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, smartdiagram

Is there any way to overlay a descriptive diagram in the **bottom-up order**?

I know that priority descriptive diagrams can be used, but aesthetically, I guess standard descriptive diagrams with custom styles for the titles look much better.

Please consider this minimal example (also using `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}`).

```
\tikzset{description title/.append style={
    signal,
    signal to=north,
    signal from=south,
    yshift=0.1cm,
    signal pointer angle=130
}}
\smartdiagramset{
    descriptive items y sep=1.3,
    description text width=4cm,
    description title text width=1.6cm,
    description width=4.5cm
}
\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]
{
    {Title3, Description 3},
    {Title2, Description 2},
    {Title1, Description 1},
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dial a negative `descriptive items y sep`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A smartdiagram}
\tikzset{description title/.append style={
    signal,
    signal to=north,
    signal from=south,
    yshift=0.1cm,
    signal pointer angle=130
}}
\smartdiagramset{
    descriptive items y sep=-1.3,
    description text width=4cm,
    description title text width=1.6cm,
    description width=4.5cm
}
\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]
{
    {Title1, Description 1},
    {Title2, Description 2},
    {Title3, Description 3},
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]